# How to run seeders with relations and UUID

Tags: eloquent, uuid

I'm busy on a project for internships now and I'm stuck at this one.

I can already generate uuid's with multiple seeders at once, but the problem is that I need generated uuid's in a couple of seeders because there are tables who needs to be related with each other by the uuid's...

So how can I fix this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For foreing keys, I used [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker)'s `randomElement` method inside factories:

```php
use App\Models\Article;
use App\Models\Visibility;
use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Article::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'id' => Uuid::generate()->string,
        'visibility_id' => $faker->randomElement(Visibility::all()->toArray())['id'],
    ];
});
```

Hope It's what your looking for!